# writing generic function using method name

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

I am trying to write the following method:

```
case class Config2(repoName: String)

def buildAction[A, M, R <: HList]()
                          (implicit
                           gen: Generic.Aux[Config2, R],
                           mod: Modifier.Aux[R, M, A, A, R])
  : (A, Config2) => Config2 = {
    (arg: A, c: Config2) => {
      val rec = mod.apply(gen.to(c), _ => arg)
      gen.from(rec)
    }
  }
```

When trying to use it with:

```
buildAction[String, Witness.`'repoName`.T, String :: HList]()
```

I get an error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[com.advancedtelematic.tuf.cli.Cli.Config2,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HList]]
[error]   val _ = buildAction[String, Witness.`'repoName`.T, String :: HList]()
```

am I missing some import here?

Second question is,  can I somehow rewrite this signature so I don't don't have to specify all the types? In practive the Config2 type takes a long list of fields so it's not pratical to write this all the time

**Update:**

I simplified this to the following:

```
  val CGen = LabelledGeneric[Config]

  def buildAction[A, M]()
                       (implicit mod: Modifier.Aux[CGen.Repr, M, A, A, CGen.Repr])
  : (A, Config) => Config = {
    (arg: A, c: Config) => {
      val rec = mod.apply(CGen.to(c), _ => arg)
      CGen.from(rec)
    }
  }
```

Which allows me to just write:

```
buildAction[String, Witness.`'repoName`.T]()
```

But I still have to specify that `Witness`. Is the a way I could write `buildAction[String]("repoName")` and have some method provide the Witness implicitly?

Update: the following works!

```
  val CGen = LabelledGeneric[Config]

  def buildAction[A](witness: Witness)
                    (implicit mod: Modifier.Aux[CGen.Repr, witness.T, A, A, CGen.Repr]):
  (A, Config) => Config = {
    (arg: A, c: Config) => {
      val rec = mod.apply(CGen.to(c), _ => arg)
      CGen.from(rec)
    }
  }

  buildAction[RepoName]('repoName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I missing some import here?

No, it's probably just that `String :: HList` must be `String :: HNil`

> Second question is, can I somehow rewrite this signature so I don't don't have to specify all the types?

You can use a trick known as [kinda-curried type parameters](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/07/30/infer.html):

```
object buildAction {
   class PartiallyApplied[A, M] {
      def apply[R <: HList]()(implicit ...)
   }
   def apply[A, M] = new PartiallyApplied[A, M]
}
```

Used as

```
buildAction[String, Witness.`'foo`.T]()
```

---

Also, since your code mentions field name, you probably want `LabelledGeneric` in conjunction with `ops.record.Updater`

Comment: Ok, I overlooked that one, thanks! I used `HNil` now `but not it cannot find the Modifier.Aux `
could not find implicit value for parameter mod: shapeless.ops.record.Modifier.Aux[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil],Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("repoName")],String,String,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]` You mean I need LabelledGeneric instead?
Also, is there a way to also abstract that Witness so I could write `buildAction[String]("foo")`?

Comment: yes, this works: `buildAction[String, Witness.`'repoName`.T, Record.`'repoName -> String`.T]()` but now I have "repoName" in Repr as well.. Willl try to apply the pattern you described.

Comment: @simao I just figured out that if you write method *accepting* `Witness` or `Witness.Aux[A]`, i.e. `def foo(w: Witness) = ???`, you can call it with literal: `foo("uux")`

Comment: It doesn't work with a string for some reason but using a symbol it converts it to a proper `Witness` and works. thanks!